# Rarity of outcome - using linear over logit models for binary outcomes

Tags: regression, logistic, linear-model

I'm looking for a reference stating a rule of thumb for when an outcome is too rare in order to use a linear over a logit model. Is it 70-30, 80-20 or something third?

I do realize other factors are of influence when deciding on a statistical model

Best regards

Comment: Its hard to put a number on it.  The principle complaint of using the linear probability model (LPM) is that can give nonsense confidence intervals, for example surpassing 0 or 1 in coverage.  If the data are numerous enough, and the probability does not change too much in as a function of the covariates, this can be combated. In general, it is wise to use a model which respects the support of the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.